# .net - Glass effect in C# 2.0 applications

Tags: winforms, .net-2.0, c#-2.0

How can I give a Vista or Mac OS X style glass effects on windows forms applications in .net 2.0?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is done using interop with the Vista DWM (Desktop Window Manager) API.

For example, import these functions:

```
[DllImport("dwmapi.dll")]
static extern void DwmExtendFrameIntoClientArea(IntPtr hWnd, ref Margins pMargins);


[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
struct Margins
{
    public int cxLeftWidth;
    public int cxRightWidth;
    public int cyTopHeight;
    public int cyBottomHeight;
}
```

Then you can use this to "pull down" glass from the top of the window down into the client area:

```
GlassMargins.Top = 40;
GlassMargins.Left = 0;
GlassMargins.Right = 0;
GlassMargins.Bottom = 0;

DwmExtendFrameIntoClientArea(this.Handle, ref GlassMargins);
```

From here, you can go on and do other things, like draw text or images onto the glass, or put controls on it, such as a Office 2007 style application button.

Answer (score 2):

The glass window borders in Vista Aero are composited using the DWM.  This is an OS-level feature.  If you run your app on Vista, you should get the glass border for free.

If you want to extend the glass effect into the client area, use [DwmExtendFrameIntoClientArea](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa969512(VS.85).aspx), which is how Internet Explorer does it in its toolbar.  I suspect you'll have to write the interop to call this native function yourself (or check http://pinvoke.net).

Answer (score 1):

**DevExpress components**

- for .NET 2.0

http://devexpress.com/Products/NET/DXperience/editionWinForms.xml

---

**Creating a Glass Button using GDI+**

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/buttons/glassbutton.aspx

Comment: This is a nice cross platform solution.