# Window glass in .NET

Tags: windows-7, windows-vista, aero-glass

[Normal border glass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/993249/net-glass-effect-in-c-2-0-applications/1626293#1626293) is nice, but how can I do the second type of transparency like middle part in the window with the list of gadgets? And what about white light on the back of text?

[windows with list of gadgets http://dajbych.net/glass.png](http://dajbych.net/glass.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually you just extend the glass frame into the client area, which is [trivial to do](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa969512%28VS.85%29.aspx). And then you draw over it, with an alpha channel. The window in question here likely draws a partially transparent white over its main client area. Some more information can be found on MSDN: [Aero Glass: Create Special Effects With The Desktop Window Manager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163435.aspx).

The light around text should be just some glow added behind. Although Windows uses it in window captions as well, so there *might* be a function rendering that. I just couldn't find it.